# How to call two methods of same controller in router

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

I have two methods that I want to call into a view(same controller). How can I do that. For example this is a route to the view

```
 Route::get('url', 'ExampleController@foo');
 Route::get('url', 'ExampleController@bar');
```

How can I merge those two.

Answer (score 0):

```
        You need to code in controller methods i.e



class ExampleController extends CI_Controller {
    public $data;
    public function foo(){
        //inside foo get the view of bar in variable i.e.
        $this->data['bar_view'] = $this->load->view('bar_view',$this->data,true);
        $this->load->view('foo_view',$this->data);
    }
    public function bar(){
        //inside foo get the view of bar in variable i.e.
        $this->data['foo_view'] = $this->load->view('foo_view',$this->data,true);
        $this->load->view('bar_view',$this->data);
    }
}


    // inside view display as the order you want
```